# JSON schema: number greater than (not greater than and equal)

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I've the following JSON config:

```
{
    "zoomLevel": {
        "min": 5,
        "max": 7
    }
}
```

The `ajv` validation should check if the `max` value is larger than the `min` value and can't be equal. I've found In the docs for the `ajv` package only the larger than or equal check and I've no idea how should I check for only the larger one. So if I use this schema:

```
"zoomLevel": {
    "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "min": {
                "type": "number",
                "minimum": 0
            },
            "max": {
                "type": "number",
                "minimum": {
                    "$data": "1/min"
                },
                "maximum": 18
            }
    }
}
```

it checks only if the `max` is larger than or equal to `min`. I need something like this:

```
"minimum": {
    "$data": "1/min + 1"
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is `exclusiveMinimum` instead of `minimum`.

Also, note that `$data` is non-standard JSON Schema.  This is something that ajv have decided to provide and will not be compatible with other validators.

Comment: See http://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#name-exclusiveminimum for the full official docs